# Use of "calloc" & "realloc"

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, realloc

**Practice**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

  int i=0,z=2;
  char *p=(char *)calloc(z,(sizeof(char)));

  if(!(p)){
    printf("\nMemory NOT Enough\n");
    goto END;
  }

  *p='V';
  z+=2;
  p=realloc(p,z*(sizeof(char)));         ----A

  *(p+3)='S';

  for(i=0;i<z;++i)
    printf("\n%d\n",p[i]);

  END:free(p);p=NULL;

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the line marked by `A` uses `realloc`.

In `line A` the `p` on the LHS of the `=` is assigned the new address generated by `realloc(p,z*(sizeof(char)));`.

My question is :

What happens to the previously stored address in `p`? Previously stored address is replaced, so does it lead to memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the return value from `realloc()` is not NULL all is well;
if `realloc()` returns NULL you have a memory leak.

You need to use a helper variable to use `realloc()` safely.

```
char *tmp;

tmp = realloc(p, z);
if (tmp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to realloc.\n");
    // p still points to the old memory and its contents are valid
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // or some other error recovery
} else {
    // tmp points to a (possibly new) block of memory with the same contents
    // as what p used to point to (to the maximum of the old size and z)
    // p (very probably) points to an invalid address
    p = tmp; // now p points to a valid address (also tmp)
    // ignore tmp for now on
}
```

Comment: When `tmp points to a (possibly new) block of memory with the same contents as what **p** used to point to` at that time the `p` points to an invalid address. So what happens to the memory block `p` previously pointed to? Is that memory block made free?

Comment: Yes, the memory `p` used to point to (if it has changed; `realloc()` can return the same address) is made free.

Comment: What is the drawback of using `realloc` without a helper variable?
And do I need to set `free(tmp);`?

Comment: If you do not use a helper variable and `realloc()` fails, `NULL` is assigned to your variable ... and you now have no way to reach the old memory (to `free()` it, or to copy to disk, or whatever): this is the memory leak

Comment: After `p=tmp` both `tmp` & `p` contains the same address & points to the same memory block. So if I set `free(p);` only, will this be enough to free the memory block `p` is pointing to? Or do I have to set `free(tmp)` as well.

Comment: After `p = tmp;` you use `p` for its purposes. Only when you no longer need that memory you free it (with `free(p);` because you are making believe `tmp` does not exist)

Comment: But in reality `tmp` exists, isn't it? Or how else would we be able to assign `p=tmp`. Now `tmp` & `p`contains the same address & points to the same memory block. My question here is that if we use any of the following : `free(p)` or `free(tmp)`, the memory block still gets freed. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. What you do not want to do is to free both `p` and `tmp` (after the first `free()` the pointer value is no longer valid and cannot be passed to `free()` again). As they have the same value, using any one for the `free()` call is ok.

Answer (score 1):

No that memory is taken care by realloc if the realloc finds sufficient memory adjascent to p then its okay else realloc moves memory to new location.note that it moves it, so old memory is freed.

Comment: So the previously stored `2 bytes` are `freed` by `realloc` & the newly assigned memory block is used to store all of the previous data.

Answer (score 0):

realloc will attempt for the extension of the available memory range only when sufficient memory is available in the heap.

From the C standard:

- size == 0

  - realloc might free old and return 0
  - alternatively realloc behaves as for size != 0 but cannot return 0
- size != 0

  - realloc might return 0. old is not touched
  - if the block pointed to by old is >= size, realloc might return old
  - alternatively realloc allocates a block >= size, copies all bytes from old up to size, frees old and returns this new block

Comment: What is `size` in your answer?